# Is there a good way to control VLC media player on my MacBook from an iOS 5 iPhone?

Tags: iphone, snow-leopard, ios, macbook-pro, vlc

I see a free application in the App Store but the reviews say it doesn't work.

I have a Snow Leopard MacBook that I hook up to my TV to watch videos sometimes. To control the video and volume, it'd be nice if I could do this from my iPhone. How could this setup be done?

Answer (score 2):

Something like [VLC Amigo](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/vlc-remco/id345490156?mt=8) (free) or VLC remote for iPhone would probably work!

Answer (score 1):

I use [Remotebuddy](http://www.iospirit.com/products/remotebuddy/). It has controls for VLC and much, much more.
You can trial it for 30 days to see how you like it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

HippoRemote is awesome for controlling VLC, iTunes player, and the Mac.

Comment: What exactly makes HippoRemote awesome?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Sybu Data Remote Control for VLC](http://www.sybu.co.za/wp/projects/iphone-ipad-remote-control-for-vlc/)

It works perfectly with OSX and iOS 5 & 6, easy to install, NO ads, and FREE.

A must have App if you have an iPhone and use VLC